# Can I give my reputation to other users?

Tags: support, answers, reputation

Does Blenderstack (and other stacks) allow to give some amount of my reputation (not limited to 15 points, but unlimited like in bounties) to other people who answer my question to thank them?
Example: @poor created an add-on, which will be super useful for me ([How to disable/enable multiple shapekeys visibility?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40621/how-to-disable-enable-multiple-shapekeys-visibility)) and I want to thank him by giving some of my reputation. Is it possible?

Comment: I feel honored :) Thanks Gonzou!

Comment: Great to hear that sir :). The add-on you wrote for me works fantastic BTW.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Outside of bounties, no. A bounty is what you are looking for.
In fact "thanking him by giving some of my reputation" is one of the reasons for offering a bounty.

> Reward existing answer
>
> One or more of the answers is exemplary and worthy of an additional bounty.

After you offer a bounty, there is a time block (24 hours) that you have to wait till you can grant it, but after that you can choose any answer on the question.

(There is another bonus, that the added exposure the bounty gives to the question may very well turn in to more UVs for the answer you want to reward.)

But no just giving rep is not allowed, for good reasons. We all want the site to stay fair.

(PS bounties are not unlimited: 500 is the max.)