# Is it possible to give away ALL reputation points as bounties to other users?

Tags: discussion, support, reputation, bounty

...of course bounties are welcome, but does it possibly contradict any stackexchange rule I'm not aware of to give away ALL my reputation points to other users over time in the form of bounties?

I don't mean transferring RP to a single user, or [targeting specific users](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/941/), but actually using all my RP over time to highlight other outstanding answers!

---

*Background:*
I earned over 24,000RP in 300 days, answered 590 questions, was the first in the world to earn the gold badge in [geometry-nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry-nodes), was elected moderator, gained [great recognition](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/273541/), and [sometimes caused a lot of headaches](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/266334/). For me, it was a rocket launch, so to speak!

And I have more than achieved my personal goals.

**And all this, only thanks to your help and approval!**

Now it's time for me to pass on this recognition and appreciation to others, I think.

One of the questions that came up in the [moderator election 2022](https://blender.stackexchange.com/election/4) was:

> [Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=blender.stackexchange.com) is not a central part of this community, and engaging in conversations there is not required nor mandatory. It is however a good way to interact with more regular visitors and socialize a bit beyond the more cold and distant everyday Q&A, since Stack Exchange is often accused of being cold and impersonal. Do you think reviving our chat rooms is a valid goal, or is it just a distraction from our main focus? Do you think it will bring users closer together a encourage users to stick around more? Do you have any ideas or suggestions to engage user in chat or encourage posting more often?
> <sub>(By the way, did you notice the typo?)</sub>

But aside from that being a nonsensical question as long as chat is so outdated and impractical in design, the real question should be how to motivate users to post great answers more often!!!

And that's where my thought comes from: If bounties are awarded more often for great answers, that might motivate some users to post even more great answers. And active engagement makes the chat more likely to be used anyway!

All I'd have to do is spend my reputation points and pick the most notable ones out of the plethora of posts.

Theoretically I could give away 50RP to at least 480 answers at the current time.

In the end, I would be your moderator with the lowest reputation, but at least I can enjoy having been a driving force for this platform for a while.

I would definitely go a way that probably no one has gone before me.

Of course, it would also make the [Bounties](https://blender.stackexchange.com/?tab=bounties) section a bit more crowded, and make other questions seem less prominent.
However, I personally find that in almost all cases the offered bounties are too small, and the questioners are much too stingy anyway, compared to the free service received.
One could invest here quiet a little more!

Would I be questioning the usual procedure? Yes, of course!
Would I break the rules with that? Maybe!

---

The only important question is whether I would break any rules with this procedure, which could have negative consequences for me or other users (deletion, sanctions, etc.) due to the automatic detection of *unusual behavior*?

Comment: I don't think you'd be breaking any specific rules, as far as I know, though it might inadvertently subvert what bounties are for. Your reputation is a visible indication of your knowledge and dedication to this site, giving it all away for the sake of the common good, while noble seems a waste of your hard earned efforts, and well deserved reward.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Hmm, thank you, good point. Of course, I'm questioning (to some degree) the usual system of bounties by doing this, since I'm really just giving away bonuses instead of looking for answers. I may not have thought it through to the end on that point. On the other hand, though, maybe it really would be a way to motivate some users, wouldn't it? Of course I worked hard to get it, but owning RP doesn't really do anything for me (or anyone else) compared to good answers... Currently it is just an idea.

Comment: "*RP doesn't really do anything for me (or anyone else) compared to good answers.*" It actually does, for other users it may well serve as some sort of "seal of quality" or vague indication of expertise, for anyone reading your posts, indicating that you are a reputable user with a good record, thus your answers are likely to be of high value. For yourself, if the rep itself means nothing to you personally, it may still be of some use as some sort of "portfolio" proof of expertise in the industry, as maybe part of a curriculum vitae.

Comment: Still an interesting idea, posting good questions even more "basic" ones that haven't been asked yet to encourage new users may be a good idea, even without the primary goal being exhausting away all your rep back to the community from the start. Maybe some interesting "challenges", well masked as a good question to not arouse the most conservative of users. Those seem to have worked well in the past, if we don't do it too often that people loose interest.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos *"Maybe some interesting "challenges", well masked as a good question to not arouse the most conservative of users. "* ...that is a big challenge from experience ;-) But a good idea. ...I will think about it.

Comment: The lovely things about this idea are self-evident :) .. my 2¢ on a couple of cautions?  1. The conversion from public to private currency risks being misinterpreted as favouritism .. distribution would have to be carefully considered, taking that into account.. and 2. perhaps some of the perceived _value_ in [bounties-to-reward-existing-answers] lies not so much in the points transferred, as in the exceptional nature of the gift.

Comment: @quellenform: FYI, rewarding existing answers is one of the options for why you're starting a bounty, so that part is a valid use of the bounty feature. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I sometimes have good ideas, and sometimes bad ones.

...This was probably a rather bad idea.

From the comments I conclude that this would be a remarkable approach in itself, but would actually upset some established systems.

1. the distribution of points would always be subjective, and the impression of favoritism could arise.
2. a really fair distribution would not be possible, because I would not be able to distribute points equally to all users in all subject areas, nor would I be equally competent in all areas to achieve a fair assessment.
3. it would possibly counteract the hard earned reputation of other users through bounties.
4. reputation points are not made to be distributed to the public, but serve the reputation of individual users (and to a certain degree in consequence also the reputation of the platform, since I am a moderator here).
5. there might be other (better) ways to get users to give excellent answers.

Therefore, I hereby close the question and consider it solved.

In principle, giving up my own reputation points would have been feasible and justifiable for me, but I realize that this makes little sense and would only be a drop in the bucket.

Nevertheless, it should not stop me from rewarding really excellent answers with a bounty, as long as it is feasible and the contribution is actually an enrichment for this platform!

Thanks anyway for your feedback!

Comment: One other note: As soon as you dropped below 75 reputation on this site (for any reason), you'd lose the [set bounties](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties). (I'm not sure how this would interact with currently active bounties; I assume you could still award them normally, just not start new ones while below 75 rep.)